# BlackBerry BBM service making use of our own BES after integrating with our app

Tags: blackberry

I am integrating BlackBerry Messenger into our BlackBerry application. We would like the integrated messenger to make use of our own BlackBerry Enterprise Server.

Is it possible, or does BBM always make use of the BES associated with the device?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any BES experience, but it would be really fishy if third-party apps could force the device to associate with a different BES, so I would guess RIM does not allow the behavior you want.